# Android download manager failed to download file with reason 1004

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-download-manager

I'm trying to download file using downloadManager but it fails with reason 1004, this issue occured when i changed the URL to HTTPS, whith HTTP it works fine.
I checked google documentation for the reason **1004**: **Value of COLUMN_REASON when an error receiving or processing data occurred at the HTTP level.**
i couldn't find any thing useful